# mysql select columns in join query

Tags: php, mysql, inner-join

**Scenario:**

Students can register in one or more classes.

**Structure:**

**students** table has columns: **id,firstname, lastname, email, dob, age, gender, mobile, address**.

**classes** table has columns: **id,name**.

**student_classes** table has columns: **student_id,class_id**

Now Iam joining 3 tables: students, classes, student_classes with an inner join query:

```
select *
from students inner join student_classes 
  on students.id=student_classes.student_id  inner join classes
  on student_classes.class_id=classes.id
```

But i don't want all the columns from the students table. I just want the firstname.
How can i modify the join query?

Comment: `SELECT *` is often considered a bad practice. Select only the columns that you need. See answers below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
s  = students table
sc = student_classes
c  = classes
```

Query:

```
select 
    sc.student_id,
    s.firstname,
    s.lastname
from students s
inner join student_classes sc on sc.student_id = s.id
inner join classes c on c.id = sc.class_id
```

Comment: It works well, just i also had to include "c.name" in the above select query, to also fetch the student's course name.

Comment: I got what i wanted, but now i get the rows such that there are multiple rows for a particular student. ( I hope, because it is one to many). For ex: one row with student id 1 and course A, and another row with student id 1 and course B. Is it possible to get all courses of a student in a single row?

Comment: For now, i dont have any other options and iam running another query to fetch the classes of a student like: SELECT name from classes where id in (select class_id from student_classes where student_id=1)

Comment: Yes, its possible you can add for example `where s.student_id = 1`
But because its a one to many relation you can't do it in one query.. 
If your server supports Stored Procedures you can do it in one query by creating a stored procedure and loop all students in it and search all courses.. But if i can quess  your a beginner in MySql so its a bit beyond your knowlegde :-) maybe a solution for later?

Comment: Thanks Tricker for your answer... if you dont mind, iam interested to know about the stored procedure for this case... can you provide a hint?

Comment: watch [here][0] for some basic knowlegd for stored procedures.
You also need to watch [this][1]. because you will need a cursor for looping your results from your first select statement.

This are the only things i can gife you atm

[0]: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-stored-procedure-tutorial.aspx
[1]: http://www.brainbell.com/tutorials/MySQL/Working_With_Cursors.htm

Answer (score 2):

Put that column in the `SELECT` clause instead of `*`.

```
SELECT students.firstname FROM ...
```

If you still want columns from the other tables, you can list them too, or use `tablename.*`

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT students.firstname FROM students
INNER JOIN student_classes ON students.id = student_classes.student_id
INNER JOIN classes ON student_classes.class_id = classes.id
```

For reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/select.html

Comment: it gives only the students' firstname, but i want columns from other tables too..

Answer (score 1):

Try this query:

```
select students.firstname from ....
```